# powershell run java process problem

Tags: command-line-interface, java, powershell

I'm trying to run a java process via Powershell in Windows XP.  Here's the command:

```
java.exe -cp .;./common.jar -Dcontext=atest1 -Dresourcepath=. DW_Install
```

So, the classpath is . and .\common.jar (I think java takes the wrong slashes, right?)  There are two environment variables, one "atest1" the other "." and the class to execute main on is DW_Install (in the default package).

This command works in cmd.exe, but doesn't is PS.  What's going on? What is PS doing while parsing this command that CMD doesn't do (or vice versa)?

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685184/powershell-run-java-process-problem).  Thanks for your help.  I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

It is powershell interpreting the args, so you will use windows style slashes.

Also, please check your history before referring to them as 'wrong'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Although PS has to read the args and do some processing of them, Java.exe will be the one to parse whatever goes through PS, right?  Specifically, I don't think PS will parse "./common.jar" as a path, right? Of course it will interpret the argument (and get rid of quotes, etc.), but it doesn't know to expect a path there.   I was feigning ignorance about the 'wrong slashes', but thanks for the correction nonetheless.